# pythonanywhere:Error code: Unhandled Exception

Tags: python, django

**hi guys.when tried deploy my django site with pythonanywhere i get an error:**

[image]

**here my WSGI configuration file:/var/www/cargoglobal_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py:**

```
import os
import sys

path = '/home/cargoglobal/CargoGlobal.net'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'elansayti.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(get_wsgi_application())
```

**and here my projects wsgi.py:**

```
"""
WSGI config for elansayti project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'elansayti.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**please help me guys.i am a very helpless.**

Comment: Have you followed any of the advice in the debugging tips on that page? In particular, looking at the error logs of your web app to see what the exception was?

Comment: i follow logs and i solve my problem.here my site:https://cargoglobal.pythonanywhere.com/